# new to PHP and having difficulty printing database record

Tags: php, database, printing

I have a database with a third party and I have downloaded it through their API.  Here is my code:

```
<?php

include_once('./rmapi.class.php');

# initilize class
$rmapi = new RMAPI('mySecretToken');

#request AccountID
$account_info = $rmapi->rm_administrationUsersCurrent();

#parse array and access the account id stdClass object value.  returns just the the account GUID as a string
$accountId = $account_info['service_response']->AccountId;

$listId = "mySecretId";

$request = json_decode("{}");

$reportSummary=$rmapi->rm_listsRecipientsFiltered($accountId, $listId, $request);

$data=$reportSummary['service_response'];

$records = count($data);

for ($i = 0; $i < $records; $i++) {
  echo "<br />";
  echo $i."  ";
  echo $data[$i]->Email;
  echo $data[$i]->lastname;
  }

echo "<br />";


?>
```

Here is what I believe is the first record:

```
array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (8) { ["BounceDate"]=> string(20) "0001-01-01T05:00:00Z" ["BounceStatus"]=> string(4) "None" ["CreateDate"]=> string(23) "2017-10-02T14:00:10.41Z" ["Email"]=> string(26) "test@test.com" ["EmailFormatPreference"]=> string(11) "TextAndHtml" ["OptOut"]=> bool(false) ["OptOutDate"]=> string(20) "0001-01-01T05:00:00Z" ["Properties"]=> array(13) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(5) "email" ["Value"]=> string(26) "test@test.co" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(9) "firstname" ["Value"]=> string(1) "first" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(8) "lastname" ["Value"]=> string(1) "last" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#8 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(7) "address" ["Value"]=> string(1) "123 main" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#9 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(4) "city" ["Value"]=> string(1) "anytown" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#10 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(5) "state" ["Value"]=> string(1) "anystate" } [6]=> object(stdClass)#11 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(3) "zip" ["Value"]=> string(1) "00000" } [7]=> object(stdClass)#12 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(5) "phone" ["Value"]=> string(1) "123-456-7890" } [8]=> object(stdClass)#13 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(8) "birthday" ["Value"]=> string(1) "01/01/01" } [9]=> object(stdClass)#14 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(11) "kr_comments" ["Value"]=> string(1) "test comment" } [10]=> object(stdClass)#15 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(10) "lastopened" ["Value"]=> string(21) "10/3/2017 11:41:22 AM" } [11]=> object(stdClass)#16 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(11) "lastclicked" ["Value"]=> string(0) "" } [12]=> object(stdClass)#17 (2) { ["Name"]=> string(10) "createdate" ["Value"]=> string(21) "10/2/2017 10:00:10 AM" } } }
```

I am new to PHP and I haven't been able to print the data.  I'm trying to print select fields from each record (i.e., email, lastname, firstname, phone).

I would appreciate some help.

Take care,
Bill

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you don't have value for $records.  You need:

```
$records = count($data);
```

Comment: I apologize but I have that line in my code.  I accidentally deleted it when I was cleaning up the code before posting.  I have updated the code in my question.